# Can't concatenate two strings in dart

Tags: string, flutter, dart

Here is my code:

```
onPressed: () {
  link = links[sessName.indexOf(str, 0)];
  print('$link.txt');
},
```

sessName - links array. For example, I will give the first element: `'http://lingvostim.com/LS2018/about'`

I need to add a `'.txt'` to the end of `link`. I don't know why string interpolation isn't working. The console displays only `'http://lingvostim.com/LS2018/about'`. I will be glad of your help.

**I found out that if you write like this: `print('**something**$link. txt');` everything works fine. Why if you write something before a variable it works?**

Comment: It really should work like that. It seems impossible to me that it doesn't print the `.txt` part. Are you sure it even enters that code? Maybe it's a print from another place you are seeing

Answer (score 0):

If you try to print your value `'http://lingvostim.com/LS2018/about'` directly, it should work fine. Just make sure your `links[sessName.indexOf(str, 0)]` expression returns expected value.

Answer (score 0):

The results if indexOf not found is -1. You should add conditional operator to set the link as empty string '' if str not found.

**Updated code**

```
onPressed: () {
  int index = sessName.indexOf(str, 0);
  String link = index != -1 ? links[index] : ''; 
  print('${link}.txt'); 
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Flutter is writing: _The left operand can't be null, so the right operand is never executed. Try removing the operator and the right operand._

Comment: Sorry the results if indexOf not found is -1 so it will be not null. you can try this code:
onPressed: () {
  int index = sessName.indexOf(str, 0);
  String link = index != -1 ? links[index] : '';
  print('${link}.txt');
},

Comment: Please, update your answer accordingly to changes suggested in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses with dollar for concatenation

`onPressed: () {`
`link = links[sessName.indexOf(str, 0)]??';`
`print('${link}.txt');`
`}`

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to remove the character at the end of the line.

```
onPressed: () {
  int index = sessName.indexOf(str, 0);
  String link = index != -1 ? links[index] : '';
  link = link.substring(0, link.length - 1);
  print('$link.txt');
},
```